# Using more than one While True loop in python turtle

Tags: python, while-loop, turtle-graphics

I am currently having an issue where every time I try to use more than one While True loop in my code the website crashes. I am coding with [python](/questions/tagged/python) turtle, a nice beginner way to get started on coding with python. So basically I am trying to have a turtle object spin in a circle infinitely until the player press the space bar. The turtle is triggered to spin when the turtle object is the color blue. Once the player pushes the button the turtle object will turn green signally it to stop turning and move forward 300 px in the direction the turtle object was facing prior to pressing the space bar. The goal of this little mini game is to hit the red ball known as the target. This target is spawned in a random location on the canvas, every time the code runs. Once the turtle object collides with the the target the score on the top of the screen will change from 0 to 1.

```
import turtle
import random

t = turtle.Turtle()
target = turtle.Turtle()
scoreBoard = turtle.Turtle()
scoreBoard.ht()
target.ht()
screen = turtle.Screen()
x = random.randint(-300,300)
y = random.randint(-300,300)
scoreNum = 0
turnSpeed = 2

t.shape('turtle')
t.color('blue')

target.speed(0)
target.penup()
target.goto(30,0)
target.shape('circle')
target.color('red')
target.st()

scoreBoard.color('orange')
scoreBoard.speed(0)
scoreBoard.penup()
scoreBoard.goto(-75,310)
scoreBoard.write('Score:' + str(scoreNum),font=('Arial',15, 'normal'))

def turnStop():
  t.color('green')
  t.forward(300)

def checkCollision():
  if abs(t.xcor() - target.xcor()) < 10 and abs(t.ycor() - target.ycor()) < 10:
    return True
  else:
    return False

screen.onkey(turnStop,'space')
screen.listen()

while t.color()[0] == 'blue':
  t.right(turnSpeed)

while t.color()[0] == 'green':  
  if checkCollision():
    scoreNum = scoreNum + 1
    scoreBoard.clear()
    scoreBoard.write('Score:' + str(scoreNum),font=('Arial',15, 'normal'))
```

So as you can see I have two while True loops. One for when the player is blue at the start of the game. This allows the turtle object to be spun forever until the player hits the space bar. And the other while true loop for when the player turns green by pressing the space bar, to check for collisions with the red ball target. But every time I press the space bar after running the code the website crashes. Any ideas?Thanks in advance!

P.S I am a student at juni learning. It is an online class where you can go and learn to code with a teacher in real time. And it comes with its own text editor so that is what I have been coding with.

P.S P.S And is there a better way to paste your code on this forum? I had to paste my code to stack overflow and indent each line of code 4 times which is kind of tedious.

Comment: IN response to your last question: Of course, there is. You can see once my edits are accepted.

Comment: So I just add ''' to my code? Example: ''' import turtle ''' Sorry if this seems dumb. This is my very first time on this forum. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so me and my teacher went over the problem I had with the code. We fixed it and now it is running like intended.

```
import turtle
import random

t = turtle.Turtle()
target = turtle.Turtle()
scoreBoard = turtle.Turtle()
scoreBoard.ht()
target.ht()
screen = turtle.Screen()
x = random.randint(-300,300)
y = random.randint(-300,300)
scoreNum = 0
turnSpeed = 2

t.shape('turtle')
t.color('blue')

target.speed(0)
target.penup()
target.goto(30,0)
target.shape('circle')
target.color('red')
target.st()

scoreBoard.color('orange')
scoreBoard.speed(0)
scoreBoard.penup()
scoreBoard.goto(-75,310)
scoreBoard.write('Score:' + str(scoreNum),font=('Arial',15, 'normal'))

def turnStop():
  t.color('green')

def checkCollision():
  if abs(t.xcor() - target.xcor()) < 10 and abs(t.ycor() - target.ycor()) < 10:
    return True
  else:
    return False

screen.onkey(turnStop,'space')
screen.listen()

while True:
  while t.color()[0] == 'blue':
    t.right(turnSpeed)

  if t.color()[0] == 'green':  
    for i in range(30):
      t.forward(10)
      if checkCollision():
        x = random.randint(-300,300)
        y = random.randint(-300,300)
        scoreNum = scoreNum + 1
        scoreBoard.clear()
        scoreBoard.write('Score:' + str(scoreNum),font=('Arial',15, 'normal'))
        target.goto(x,y)
        t.penup()
        t.goto(0,0)
        t.color('blue')
        t.pendown()
        break
    else:
      break
```

Basically I had to nest a while True loop in my while color is blue loop along side my conditional to check if the code is green. Thanks to anyone who responded, for trying to help me with my problem! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

When you've two for-loops one will never be reached until the other is finished.
Why don't you use another if condition in your mainloop?

```
while t.color()[0] == 'blue':  
    if t.color()[0] == 'green':
        t.right(turnSpeed)
```

PS: first paste, then mark all as code

Comment: I tried your code but now the turtle object doesn't seem to be moving at all. Mind you my turtle starts out blue and once the player hits the space bar it turns green.

Comment: oh sorry then I should switch the conditions

Comment: So, I switched the colors and now it seems the website is crashing every time press the space bar just like how it was crashing with two While True loops. It might just be the website's problem, I am not sure. Mind you, I commented out both While True loops before adding your variation.